# How to create a measure which counts the # of row divide by the total # of row

Tags: powerbi

I have a table like this:

Table

| Name | HasEntry | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | true | jan 22 |
| A | false | jan 22 |
| A | true | jan 22 |
| A | true | jan 22 |
| B | true | jan 22 |
| B | false | jan 22 |
| B | true | jan 22 |

I want a measure with gives `Ratio = "# of HasEntry = true / # of row of each name"

that mean for A the ratio is 3/4 = 0.75, B is 2/3 = 0.66

I tried doing

```
Ratio = DIVIDE(COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table, Table[HasENtry] = TRUE)), COUNT(Table[HasENtry]))
```

But when I use the ratio in my y-axis of the line chart, I get error 'Can't display the visul

'The function COUNT cannot work with values of type BOOLEAN?

So how to count the # of row for each name in my measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTA() instead on booleans.

https://dax.guide/counta/